# PostgreSQL: Realizing columns depending on other tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm currently learning the basics of SQL and now I'm facing the following problem. The implementation of it will be in PostgreSQL.

Let's say you have the two following tables in your database:

1. department(dpID:PK, ..., avg_salary)
2. employee(eID:PK, ..., dpID:FK REF department, salary)

(PK = Primary Key, FK = Foreign Key)

So every employee has a salary and a department, every department should store the average salary of its employees (not just in a view).

Of course there should be some kind of update rule in the database, so when a new employee gets inserted, the avg_salary of the employees department gets updated / recalculated.

So when there are e.g. currently no employees in a department X, the avg_salary should be 0. After inserting an employee in department X with a salary of 1000, the avg_salary should be 1000.

Calculating the avg_salary wouldn't be a problem with a sql query.

```
SELECT AVG(e.salary) FROM empoyee e WHERE e.dpID = ...
```

But I'm stuck at finding a way to use this result to solve my problem.

So I would be very glad for ideas to realize the function of automatically (re-)calculating attribute values with the result of an aggregation function used on a different table.

Thank you and have a nice day! :)

Comment: the average is a derived value, you **don't save it** you calculate it when need be. else you need a lot of trigger to keep it uptodate

Comment: As others point out recalculating the department average after DML on employee **is a very bad plan**. If however you insist on doing so then you also need to consider: What happens when an employee's salary changes (+/-)? What happens when an employee leaves? What happens when an employee leaves and there is a legal requirement to maintain the data for some time period? What happens when an employee changes departments? If you are going to recalculate you need triggers - and they will quite likely not be simple.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your arguments are completely right. The question was asked in context of a small university project where I was directly asked to do it like I asked above. In the end I solved it with a trigger, of course that's not how it would have been done in a real world scenario, but did its job for the task. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with nbk, you shouldn't use a function to recalculate.
What I would do is create a view. Something like this

```
create view deptview as select d.name, coalesce(avg(salary),0) from employee e right join department d on e.dpId=d.id group by d.name;
```

It will recalculate the average every time you use the deptview view

To see your data just

```
select * from deptview;
```